# Webservice import set field mapping in servicenow

Tags: servicenow

i have a requirement to import data via the web service import set feature in ServiceNow.

My request body is actually a nested JSON object, where I would like one of fields to contain the inner JSON, then I can further process the data in transform script.

however the value in the input row some how becomes comma separated key=value

Has anyone seen this behavior? and if so how would I disable it.

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide a sample of your json payload

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that the web service import uses ONLY CSV style attachments. If you wish to use JSON you'll have to use the REST api to update records one at a time.
If you can convert your JSON to CSV, that should allow you to use the import functionality. But I realize that might be easier said than done.